# Probability in Euro Jackpot

Tags: probability

I was looking at rewards for euro jackpot. Rules are as follow. You need to guess $5$ out of $50$ numbers and $2$ out $8$ numbers to get jackpot. There are also lower gains for which you need to for example, guess $\frac{3}{50}$ and $\frac{1}{8}$ to get some smaller amount of money.

Thing that bothers me is $2$ lowest awards. There's $\frac{1}{50}+\frac{2}{8}$ and $\frac{2}{50}+\frac{1}{8}$.

Somehow it seems harder to guess $\frac{2}{50}+\frac{1}{8}$ than $\frac{1}{50}+\frac{2}{8}$ yet you get more money if you guess $\frac{1}{50}+\frac{2}{8}$.

Can someone explain to me how that math works and why is $2+1$ more probable than $1+2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you submit a five-element subset of $\{1,\ldots,50\}$ and a two-element subset of $\{A,B,\ldots,H\}$ as guesses, then random subsets of the same sizes are drawn and the winning class is calculated by the set intersections between your guesses and the drawn sets.

The probability of guessing exactly 1 out of 50 and 2 out of eight, is $$\frac{{5\choose 1}\cdot{45\choose 4}}{50\choose 5} \cdot \frac{{2\choose 2}{6\choose 0}}{8\choose 2}\approx 0.012557462855632539787422832222620778191$$
and for 2 out of fifty and 1 out of eight it is 
$$\frac{{5\choose 2}\cdot{45\choose 3}}{50\choose 5} \cdot \frac{{2\choose 1}{6\choose 1}}{8\choose 2}\approx 0.028702772241445805228395045080276064437$$
so the first combination is harder to get. Assuming the lottery pays out only half (after all, lotteries are intended as taxes on non-mathematicians) the first should pay about $40:1$, the second only about $17:1$.